# 404 on google cached version pages

Tags: search-engine-indexing, cache, crawl-errors

When I am searching my website on Google cache version is showing 404 errors. I tested same for some other competitors also and the same problem is there. Reviewed on Google Search Console, all good there. But does anyone know why is so happening and how can I get cached version now?

[image]

Comment: You need to wait. As long as everything is good in GSC rendering option, your site is ok.

Comment: All good on GSC and ealier I was able to see cache version also with text & graphic version and last date of crawling info. But sudden even not a single page is showing cached version. Tried to build some backlink to one of the page, so that is showing cached version. Can't do off page for all pages of website. Bit worried why this is this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John Muller from Google answered a similar [question](https://www.reddit.com/r/bigseo/comments/8bof1b/google_cache_url_going_for_404/dx8hj9w) at Reddit:

[image]

It seems to be linked to Google's [switching](https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/1001017941389869057) to **Mobile-first indexing**:

[image]